# How to programmatically share Android device's screen with another via wifi? (not screenshot)

Tags: android, screen, wifi, screensharing

i must write an app that shares my android device's screen with anothers.(not screenshot) 
I searched on the internet a lot but i didnt find an answer.

Is it possible? Does android let us to do that?

How can i do that?

Comment: Please explain what "shares my android device's screen with anothers" means that somehow does not involve a screenshot.

Comment: I also want to create this type of app. If you got any idea please share with me.

Comment: Got solution for this criteria? Tell me how if you say yes.

Comment: Hi,I researched this a lot and I figured out that ; android does not let 3.party applications to take screen shots (only android OS takes screen shots )because it may cause security bugs,such as copying passwords etc. So we switched the project from android to windows